# How can I implement XFBML versions of my plugins belonging to two different apps, i.e. using two different app ID:s?

Tags: facebook-like, xfbml, facebook-comments

I have until now used different implementations for my Facebook like and comment plugins on my site: the like plugin was implemented first, using an iframe and the comment plugin was implemented later, using XFBML and the Facebook SDK.

When I implemented the Facebook comments plugin, I needed an app in order to moderate the comments. The site already add an app, but I wanted to have an app just to moderate the comments, so I created a new one for that purspose only.

I would now like to replace the Like plugin's iframe implementation with an XFBML one.

Question 1: Is it possible to have two different app ID:s, one for the comments plugin and the other for the like plugin defined in the Facebook SDK?

Question 2: If not possible use two different app ID:s, how can I gather the data from both the like plugin and the facebook comments plugin into one of my apps?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have more than one application initializations on one page. Even if you try to add application as parameter to JS-SDK it may lead to unexpected behavior.

Whyle gathering data is possible you will not be able to transfer data between different Objects. Tis isn't really needed as long as URL remains the same, likes and comments are tied to URL, not an application.

Just continue to use one application and leave URLs for Like Button and Comments social plugins as is.

**Note:** I'm not sure about behavior of comments moderation tool, so you may want to try if you able to manage comments from the application you want before final switch to single application. If you not able to manage comments from application used for likes you may use one that already works for comments moderation.